# OR-tools routing constraint, that compares demand and capacity

Tags: python, routes, constraints, or-tools

Currently working on a routing problem and our transport has a specific condition - it can't travel half-full (delivers hazardous liquids), so basically it should be empty or almost empty after visiting the first Node. How do i add such a constraint that can compare both the demand of the node and capacity of the truck, all constraints I've seen only work with vehicle capacity?

We have multiple capacity constraints that generate iteratively, because the trucks can deliver multiple types of liquids. Don't really have an idea how to add the new constraint though.

## demands by types is a list of lists for different demands

## capacities by type is also a list of lists for every car

```
    def demand_callback(type):
        def callback(from_index):
            from_node = manager.IndexToNode(from_index)
            return data["demands_by_types"][type][from_node]

        return callback

    for type in range(len(data["demands_by_types"])):  #
        routing.AddDimensionWithVehicleCapacity(
            routing.RegisterUnaryTransitCallback(demand_callback(type)),
            0,  # null capacity slack
            data["capacities_by_type"][type],  # vehicle maximum capacities
            True,  # start cumul to zero
            f'Capacity_type_{type}'
        )
```

Answer (score 0):

In order to ensure that the vehicle is either empty or almost empty after visiting the first node, you can create a custom constraint. The logic should compare the demand of the first node with the capacity of the vehicle. Given the complex nature of your problem with multiple types of liquids and iterative capacity constraints, implementing such a constraint may require a nuanced approach.

Here's a potential way to introduce such a constraint within your current setup:

## Create a new callback to calculate the remaining capacity:

This callback can be designed to calculate the remaining capacity of a vehicle after visiting the first node for each type of liquid.

```
def remaining_capacity_callback(type):
    def callback(from_index, to_index):
        from_node = manager.IndexToNode(from_index)
        to_node = manager.IndexToNode(to_index)
        if to_node == 1:  # Assuming node 1 is the first node to be visited
            remaining_capacity = data["capacities_by_type"][type] - data["demands_by_types"][type][from_node]
            return remaining_capacity
        return 0  # return 0 for other nodes, or handle other cases as needed
    return callback
```

## Register this callback and add a new dimension:

```
for type in range(len(data["demands_by_types"])):
    remaining_capacity_callback_index = routing.RegisterTransitCallback(
        remaining_capacity_callback(type)
    )
    routing.AddDimension(
        remaining_capacity_callback_index,
        0,  # null capacity slack
        data["capacities_by_type"][type],  # vehicle maximum capacities
        True,  # start cumul to zero
        f'Remaining_Capacity_type_{type}'
    )
```

## Add a constraint on the new dimension:

You can now add a constraint to ensure that the remaining capacity after the first node is either zero or close to zero.

```
remaining_capacity_dimension = routing.GetDimensionOrDie(f'Remaining_Capacity_type_{type}')
for vehicle_id in range(data['num_vehicles']):
    first_node_index = routing.Start(vehicle_id)
    routing.solver().Add(
        remaining_capacity_dimension.CumulVar(first_node_index) <= threshold  # your defined threshold
    )
```

In the code snippet above:

A new callback remaining_capacity_callback is defined to calculate the remaining capacity after visiting the first node.
This callback is registered and a new dimension Remaining_Capacity_type_{type} is added to the routing model.
A constraint is added to ensure that the remaining capacity at the first node is below a certain threshold.
This should ensure that the vehicle is empty or almost empty after visiting the first node, as per your requirement. Please adjust the logic as needed to match the exact behavior and structure of your routing problem